Why can't my pyenv install any version of Python?
I have a Macbook M3 Pro and tansfered all of my content from an older Intel Pro. I have pyenv installed but I get a build error when I try to install any version of Python. Here's an example:
python-build: use openssl@3 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.11.9.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.9/Python-3.11.9.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.11.9...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use ncurses from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ashtonsperry/.pyenv/versions/3.11.9/lib/python3.11/curses/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
WARNING: The Python curses extension was not compiled. Missing the ncurses lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ashtonsperry/.pyenv/versions/3.11.9/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 100, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (OS X 14.5 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/p3/7nvxx8mx4x19125mj6fnjj0h0000gn/T/python-build.20240708161245.10785
Results logged to /var/folders/p3/7nvxx8mx4x19125mj6fnjj0h0000gn/T/python-build.20240708161245.10785.log

Last 10 log lines:
        DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/folders/p3/7nvxx8mx4x19125mj6fnjj0h0000gn/T/python-build.20240708161245.10785/Python-3.11.9 ./python.exe -E -m ensurepip \
            $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
    fi
Looking in links: /var/folders/p3/7nvxx8mx4x19125mj6fnjj0h0000gn/T/tmp8_w0_bq0
Processing /var/folders/p3/7nvxx8mx4x19125mj6fnjj0h0000gn/T/tmp8_w0_bq0/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /var/folders/p3/7nvxx8mx4x19125mj6fnjj0h0000gn/T/tmp8_w0_bq0/pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip3 and pip3.11 are installed in '/Users/ashtonsperry/.pyenv/versions/3.11.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-24.0 setuptools-65.5.0

I understand it has something to do with Apple's new M-chips, and I do know that my Brew is running on x86 while my system is arm64. But I have no idea what to do to fix the problem. I've tried Python 3.9.x, 3.10.x, and 3.11.x with no success. This all started with my tensorflow killing my kernel on my Jupyter Notebooks.

Check the wiki link in the error? https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#error-the-python-ssl-extension-was-not-compiled-missing-the-openssl-lib

after installing pyenv, did you configure your shell environment? do so if you haven't. to configure shell, refer to installation guide at https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv?tab=readme-ov-file#installation. also have you installed xcode command line tools? you'll need the tools.
then, you may need to install build dependencies before installing your preferred python version. use this script: brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib tcl-tk. see https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment.
you'll also need to install ncurses, which is required by apple silicon machines running macOS 14+.
"Installing versions of Python >=3.12.1 on some machines may require ncurses, which seem to be missing. Install it with: brew install ncurses" (see https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems).

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
